# A dropdownlist with delimiters or similar in C#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox, delimiter, textfieldparser

I am currently building a super common csv reader to a DataTable.
This is how my code to the TextFieldParser currently look:

```
using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
{
    // Solution to HDR problem: When getting to the checkbox part of the application,
    // just keep the HDR unchecked.
    csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
    // Can be true depending on if the csv document rows are enclosed in quotes or
    // not. Delimiters are set as either ; or , depending on weather the csv columns
    // are split with ; or , 
    csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
    string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
    foreach (string column in colFields)
    {
        DataColumn Titel = new DataColumn(column);
        Titel.AllowDBNull = true;
        csvData.Columns.Add(Titel);

        DataColumn LastName = new DataColumn(column);
        LastName.AllowDBNull = true;
        csvData.Columns.Add(LastName);

        DataColumn AbstrNum = new DataColumn(column);
        AbstrNum.AllowDBNull = true;
        csvData.Columns.Add(AbstrNum);

        DataColumn PosterTitel = new DataColumn(column);
        PosterTitel.AllowDBNull = true;
        csvData.Columns.Add(PosterTitel);

        DataColumn Workshop = new DataColumn(column);
        Workshop.AllowDBNull = true;
        csvData.Columns.Add(Workshop);

        DataColumn Keywords = new DataColumn(column);
        Keywords.AllowDBNull = true;
        csvData.Columns.Add(Keywords);

        DataColumn Institution = new DataColumn(column);
        Institution.AllowDBNull = true;
        csvData.Columns.Add(Institution);

        DataColumn CollabEmail = new DataColumn(column);
        CollabEmail.AllowDBNull = true;
        csvData.Columns.Add(CollabEmail);
    }
    ...
}
```

But I would really like to place this part in a dropdownlist 
or similar with the other possible
choices of ";" and " ":

```
csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
```

I have placed the code with the other code parts in a controller action result with a view that take the result of the DataTable to be able to change some results and then add it to the database.

I just want the user that is adding the csv file to be able to pick the delimiters while still inside the TextFieldParser.

Been searching for hours.
Impossible?

Comment: Are you asking how to read a value from a dropdown and put it in a string array?

Comment: If you need help with dropdowns and checkboxes, then ask a question about dropdowns and checkboxes. And don't forget to add a tag really relevant to this problem (`winforms`, `asp.net`, `wpf`, others?). `csv`, `delimiter`, and `textfieldparser` are related to  completely different problems.

Comment: My problem is that I need to make something like a dropdownlist inside the textfieldparser to store the delimiters "," ";" and "tab" so that the user can pick between the alternatives instead of having a default delimiter for every csv text file. But dropdownlists seem to not be allowed inside a textfieldparser so my question is if there is an alternative to dropdownlist so the user can still pick the delimiter?